# Move text in sub-menu under the parent

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working to convert a site to a completely new theme in Wordpress. The original site is here:

[Original](http://seiler.com/)

The new dev site is here:

[Dev site](http://dev.icsandbox.com/)

What I am trying to do is make the menu match as closely as possible to the original site. I am fairly intermediate on CSS so I have the following questions:

1. How can I make the sub-menu text left align with the parent menu text?
2. How can I get that pointer to point at the parent menu?

Please note that I am using a plugin called Max Mega Menu for the dev site.

Max Mega Menu includes a location to add custom styling. There is an example at their site:

[Max Mega Menu Styling Example](http://www.maxmegamenu.com/documentation/styling-sub-menus/)

Comment: It is always better to include the relevant code in your question, as those links will likely be invalid in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things to achieve sub-menu like in [selier.com](http://seiler.com/).

First, you create an empty div which will appear on parent menu hover, and which will have width of 100%. This div will be your semi-transparent background.

Then, for each sub-menu you create, set its background to none, limit its width to some value, and set its `position` property to `absolute`.

Also, make sure that the sub-menu shows on top of the background div.

This should do it.

Comment: The problem is that this is a WordPress site and they need to utilize the wordpress menu tool to display this menu so that in the future they have the flexibility to change the menu without a developer's intervention.

Comment: Wordpress or not, you can make it the way I described.

Comment: What you describe would work if I didn't need to utilize the wordpress menu creation tool. Without a large amount of customization to the existing theme I cannot tell the wordpress menu tool where to display the menu and I would need to do that to make your idea work.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better not to use any plugin and used the custom html menu to get the exact menu like in the demo.

Comment: AS mentioned on the comment below, this is a Wordpress site and the client needs to be able to use the wordpress menu editor to create the menu so that any changes in the future will not require a developer's intervention.

Comment: Off topic, but "below" may not work forever. Just say "As mentioned elsewhere" :)